# Angular Js. Click on a table cell and show the cell details in a pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs.
I have an application which shows list of records in a Table.
eg: 
EmpNo   Name
1       AAAA
2       BBBB
3       CCCC
Now I want to click on EmpNo in this table and I should see a pop up (new Html Template) which should have all the other employee records associated with the selected EmployeeNo.

eg:
if a person clicks on EmpNo: 1 the data in pop should be: 
EmpNo: 1
Name: AAAA
Unit: XYZ
Manager's Name: LLLL
An example would be of great help.
Thanks in advance.
Below is some sample code from my application

**HTML:**

```html
<a href ui-sref="stateTruckDetails({transferSessionId: x.transferSessionId})">{{x.location}}</a>
```

**JavaScript**: for application state

```js
app.config(function($stateProvider,TRANSFER_COMPONENT_PATH) 
           { 
  $stateProvider
  .state("stateTruckDetails", 
         { url: "/transfers/truckDetails/:transferSessionId", 
          controllerAs: "truckDetailsCtrl", 
          controller: "TruckDetailsController", 
          params: { tansferSessionId: $stateProvider.transferSessionId } 
         }); 
});
```

JavaScript for my controller which my pop up needs to use.

```js
app.controller('TruckDetailsController', function (transferService, $scope, dataShare, $stateParams)
               { 
  //The below is api call. Ideally this number 13 (ID) should come from the details page. 
  
  ctrl.GetTruckDetails = transferService.getTruckDetails(13).then(function (d) 
  { 
    $scope.data = d; 
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (value, index) 
    { 
      console.log(index); 
    });
  }); 
}; }); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Diana for your valuable suggestions. However, I was able to resolve it.
Here's the plunkr that I created.

http://plnkr.co/edit/i1d3P8keTcMwWQ0sIn9h

Here's the key to it. I used states for displaying both the parent and child pages.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("managerState", {
      url: "/ManagerRecord",
      controller: "myController",
      templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .state("employeeState", {
      url: "empRecords",
      parent: "managerState",
      params: {
        empId: 0
      },
      onEnter: [
        "$modal",
        function($modal) {
          $modal.open({
            controller: "EmpDetailsController",
            controllerAs: "empDetails",
            templateUrl: 'empDetails.html',
            size: 'sm'
          }).result.finally(function() {
            $stateProvider.go('^');
          });
        }
      ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first bind each row to call a function you will have to add in your controller for example openDetails. your html would look something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items"><td ng-click="openDetails(item)">Name</td></tr>
```

in your controller you will have to create this method:

```
$scope.openDetails = function(item) {
//open here popup
}
```

There are several ways to open a popup from angularjs.

1 - The best way is to use bootstrap together with angularjs - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ seach there for 'Modal' example

2 - But there is an alternative - http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

3 - And the last and desperate is to use jquery inside angularjs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Diana.
I have already followed this approach. But it doesn't work that well in my case.
Since on the click of the table cell, I need to select that Emp Id, and then pass that to call an api which will give me all the details for that employee and I need to show those in the new template.
So I was trying to use stateProvider and factory to do this.
I have edited my question and have put some snippet in there.
Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Based on the code above, your onclick event will already pass the entire item to the openDetails.
Here is a plunker with implementation for angularjs with bootstrap.
http://plnkr.co/edit/A45mnHQlwcTLSiSnHPmQ?p=preview